NextJS 14.X.X - Get explicit error messages in production with server components
Context:
NextJS 14.0.3, Typescript, App router
Separated backend API
Containerized deployment with docker/docker-compose on a Ubuntu server.
Local dev environment: WSL 2 (Ubuntu), locally deployed containerized API.
In this application, I wanted to handle errors almost identically, whether they are client or server side.
If client-side errors are emitted, I intercept them and play various effects, such as toasting the error message.
As for server components, I use the errors boundaries as per design. Doing so, NextJS censors error message outputs in production (NODE_ENV=production") as follows:

An error occurred in the Server Component render. The specific message is omitted in production builds to avoid leaking sensitive details. A digest property is included in this error instance which may provide additional details about the nature of the error.
Error digest : XXXXXXXXXXXXX

As I control all kind of emitted errors and some contain essential feedbacks for the user, I wonder if there is a way to perform a clean error handling for server components as well and preserve a clean UX.
Code bits for implementation details :
error.tsx:
'use client';
import React from 'react';
import type { Metadata } from 'next';
import { ErrorContent } from '@/app/components/atomic';

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: 'My Title',
  description: 'Something went wrong',
};

export default function Error({
  error,
  reset,
}: {
  error: Error & { digest?: string };
  reset: () => void;
}) {
  return <ErrorContent {...{ error, reset }} />;
}

As I couldn't extend the Error class to create a custom HttpError class (with status property for instance) and use the extended class with an error.tsx file, I found this kind of workaround, aggregating the status in the error message :
page.tsx:
import React from 'react';
import { cookies } from 'next/headers';
import { ssrRequest } from '@/utils';
import { Schema, shipDefaultValuesSchema } from '@/schemas';
import type { Metadata } from 'next';
import { notFound } from 'next/navigation';

export const generateMetadata = async ({
  searchParams,
}: {
  searchParams: { ship_id: string };
}): Promise<Metadata> => {
  try {
    const id = searchParams.id;
    const data= await ssrRequest(
      `${process.env.API_URL}/sata/${id}`,
      schema,
      'GET',
      cookies()
    );
    return data;
  } catch (error) {
    if (error instanceof Error) {
      if (error.message.includes('404')) return notFound();
      throw error;
    }
    throw new Error('Metadata generation failed');
  }
};

